# How to set a tab active of just opened link

Tags: javascript

I'm clicked by the `<a href="/link/">` element. But this link opened in hte new non-active tab. How to set the tab in which this link opening to be active?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
<a href="/link/" target=\"_blank\">
```

If you still don't get it in a new tab which has got focus, then it has got someting to do with browser's settings.